# Surrender vs medication?

Tags: philosophy

I wanted to find out what Hinduism says about this matter:

Its a bit hard to put into exact words, but basically, if a person has a medical condition and is given prescription medication by a doctor, and if the person chooses to consume the medication for relief -  then how does that person qualify to be in complete surrender? Because the relief is coming from the medicine - one might argue the medication itself could be God's will. But I think I'd be hard pressed to find a definite source that suggests medicine can be taken as God's will?

However, if one is in complete surrender to God and believes God is the only refuge then  that person consuming medicines negates surrender? While I note that modern prescription drugs weren't available long ago, there must have been some sort of healing that was on offer back then (eg, honey or healing mantras). I am interested to know what different schools of Hindu thought have to say on this or if there is a general consensus on such a dilemma.

Comment: So, taking medication is not necessarily a negation of surrender to God. It's more like working together with God to achieve healing and well-being

Comment: Do you think , ayurveda treatises like charaka samhita etc. is an impediment for surrender? (Now modern medicine s are only widely available in practice).Only upon achivement of the  the goal  of *mam EKAM Sharanam vraja* (surrender), all means, to achive the goal may be forfeited.One of the litmus tests as per Gita,  (eligibility test for surrender) is *sama-loshtashma-kanchanah* , ie. If one can value piece of iron , clay and gold.. all  to be the same.

Comment: @Athrey I think medical texts are there to provide relief to the body (and to an extent to the mind). I want to focus on finding out whether an individual turning towards medical texts/medicines/recreational drugs is turning away from surrender, leading to contesting of the understanding of surrender (God is the only refuge).

Comment: It depends on the Individuals position (Gita 6.3).If  an individual is a mere(beginner) aspirant of surrender, yet to rise above all worldly needs , he/she may not be able to forfeit a medicene that is imperative for survival, yet can choose avoid a recreational drug for the sake of spiritual progress. The unwavering attitude/aspiration for surrender, would slowly release the aspirant from worldly ties , consequently there would come a stage where even the medicine for survival can  be forfeited. An aspirant can be at any stage. One should know their level

Comment: Maybe the reason that the physician wants you to take the medicine is because you surrendered to God and the Lord wants you to take the medicine...maybe your own ego doesn't want to take the medicine and is making excuses. Don't overthink. there is no dilemma.

Comment: the surrender characteristic is not u.  u r very wise person so acquiring is not the way, medication is not a way, no way is your characteristic